# Fail to install visual studio 2017 for mac

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I have downloaded the visualstudioinstaller.dmg (which proves my network works), but while installing, the visual studio check the network connections and say 'no network'. And then i send the error report by network after that(what embarrassment.)
my question is:

1. how to solve this issue? my network absolute works, is the website on Microsoft down?
2. or else where can i have the offline install package of vs2017 for mac?

Thank you.

Comment: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-mac/ ... TRY FROM HERE

Comment: hi all, finally i find this notice  **An offline installer feature is planned for future versions of Visual Studio for Mac.**  : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/create-offline-installer

Comment: hmm You have to downoad .. iso, which size is (25mb) is online installer ... for .. bcoz currently there is no any offline download ,, for MAC

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/installation ... Follow This steps for installation ..

Comment: @RïshïKêsh Kümar Do you know what's the possibility of network error while downloading? i suspect it's microsoft down.

Comment: can  you upload image ... with network error ,..  So i can

Comment: The installation process is quite straight forward, i stopped at step 4, according to that doc.

Comment: what do you mean upload image? the image i download? glad you are come from Microsoft. I was too. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145258/discussion-between-dingli-and-rishikesh-kumar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i find this notice  **An offline installer feature is planned for future versions of Visual Studio for Mac.**  :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/create-offline-installer

Answer (score 1):

You Can Easily **Download Iso Image** File Of `Visual Studio For Your Mac Os` From [Here...](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-mac/)

> You Can Find The Documentation For How To Download With Steps by Steps
>   Process.. From Below Link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/installation

Comment: Thank you, but the "view Manual Installation Instructions" doesn't show on my machine, do you have a screenshot or so for the manual instructions?